Background-image won't show up when using routing group laravel 10
I'm confuse why the bg-img won't show up, as far as I know I'm using the correct path for the bg-img. But I did tried to change the bg to a color, and it did show up. Is this a laravel problem or something is wrong with my codes? I'm pretty sure I did not put any background-color styles in the content part, that's why I'm confused why the image won't show up.
Code for the bg-img:
<div class="container pt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-5 pt-5" style="color: white; margin-top: 40px">
                @yield('contentForgotPass')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<style>
    body{
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("images/bg/sv-building.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: gray;

    }
    .mb-3 input {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

</style>

Code for the Master file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

          <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.bunny.net">
        <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])

    </head>
    <body>
        @include('layouts.account.bgForgotPass')

    </body>


</html>

